# django html/css windows mac problem width additional space on the top of the page

Tags: html, css, django

my problem is really strange... We are developing shopping-cart system in django. The problem is, when I change anything even single letter on my computer, strange space on the top of the page appears, see the picture... I don't know since when the problem appears. But if i go back to previous version (in this case 210, we use svn), everything is ok, until i change something. I'm using windows 7 and i tried to edit this file in notepad, notepad++, e and so on... In the case when my friend changes something in this 210 version on Macbook everything is ok. Have anyone any ideas? Also in source code of the page strange "-" is added before doctype, but it is only visible in chrome. But the problem is for all browsers...!

what is more... for example my home page extends, categories.html and base.html, and in this case a have two "--". Of course If i change something in this two files base and home... PLEASE HELP!:)

http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/5655/buguh.png
  [2]:

re: the only difference is that "-" visible in chrome source. As I said... everything is ok for example I have

Something

and i change it to

Somethingg

the space appears. what is more, when i change it once more to previous version I mean to

Something

the space is still there :/

I had this problem before, I edited it on mac and saved. Then when I changed it on windows, it was ok. But now it does not work.

Comment: Maybe you could post a bit of the HTML that's generated with and without the problem? You probably have a typo in one of your templates.

Comment: Can you post a link? This is often easy to sort out with Firebug.

Comment: this is the link: http://shop.subeli.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have some hidden characters somewhere I don't know what editor you use but most of them have the option to show the hidden characters or [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) Still it will be good to see the source code.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but google now links here, so here's the correct answer:

You need to specify no margin or padding explicitly in CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```